# ASP.Net Repeater Binding But Not Render Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have written code for simple repeater control in asp.net
the repeater binding the data correctly but rendering is missing some data !!

there is my code :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="dayRepeater"  runat="server" >
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table id="tes-table"  width="100%"  border="0" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr >
                            <th >Column1</th>
                            <th >Column2</th>
                            <th >Column3</th> 
                            <th >OFF_PEAK</th>
                        </tr>

                    </HeaderTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>
                           <tr >
                            <td><%# Eval("DayName") %></td>

                        </tr>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>

                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

**And this is the behind code in Page_Load :

```
private readonly string[] _daysText = {
    DaysOfWeek.SATURDAY.ToString(),
    DaysOfWeek.SUNDAY.ToString(),
    DaysOfWeek.MONDAY.ToString(),
    DaysOfWeek.TUESDAY.ToString(),
    DaysOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.ToString(),
    DaysOfWeek.THURSDAY.ToString(),
    DaysOfWeek.FRIDAY.ToString(),
 };
 for (int j = 0; j < _daysText.Length; j++)
        {
            repeaterModel.Add(new TesRepeaterDataSource
            {
                DayName = _daysText[j],

            });
        }
  dayRepeater.DataSource =repeaterModel;
  dayRepeater.DataBind();
```

**The data binding correctly :

**The Binding**
[image: the binding]

**The Final View**
[image: the final view]

*Notes* :
I tried to binding data in `page_init` but the same
the browser doesn't show any data so it is not hidden from css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items with an uneven index (1:Sunday, 3:Tuesday, 5:Thursday) get handled by the `AlternatingItemTemplate`.
This `AlternatingItemTemplate` contains no binding expression, so nothing gets rendered.

Either remove this `AlternatingItemTemplate` tag, so that all items get rendered by the `ItemTemplate`.

Or add a binding expression into the `AlternatingItemTemplate`:

```
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr><td><%# Eval("DayName") %></td></tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```